# Powershell: Can't access value from file when key is a variable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I can't seem to return the value that matches the key, when the key is a variable.

I start out with a file named `projects.txt` that looks like this:

```
"ID","Name"
"0d769684e36e4cee83b26e8a2b42401b","admin"
"1ba56baa693841199c21b822ccd21dd4","Support"
```

I then make a second file in `key=value` pair format by:

```
foreach ($line in (Get-Content -encoding ASCII .\projects.txt | select-object -skip 1)){
  $proj_array = $line.split(',')
  $proj_id = $proj_array[0] -Replace '"',""
  $proj_name = $proj_array[1]
  "$proj_id=$proj_name" | out-file -append -encoding ASCII projects_hash.txt
}
```

`projects_hash.txt` looks like this:

```
0d769684e36e4cee83b26e8a2b42401b="admin"
1ba56baa693841199c21b822ccd21dd4="Support"
```

So now I'm trying to return the value matching the id by (`proj_id` is defined earlier):

```
  $projects = convertfrom-stringdata (get-content .\projects_hash.txt -raw)
  $proj_name = "$projects.$proj_id"
  Write-Host "Project name is $proj_name"
```

Which outputs:

```
Project name is System.Collections.Hashtable.2dbba23a878e47b19e6913315edfb3ef
Project name is System.Collections.Hashtable.3b4cb7dc3ebf4177b00bbee0c6bb5c12
```

If I change the line `$proj_name = $projects.$proj_id` to `$proj_name = $projects[$proj_id]` I get this output:

```
Project name is System.Collections.Hashtable[3b4cb7dc3ebf4177b00bbee0c6bb5c12]
```

How can I successfully retrieve the value matching the key?

Comment: Seems like your file `projects.txt` is actually a proper csv file. Why don't you treat it as such? It would make your life easier I think.  ;-)

Comment: you need to wrap the key in quotes to use it for lookups. you otta be able to use `$projects.'0d769684e36e4cee83b26e8a2b42401b'` to get `"admin"` if you want to be rid of the quotes on the value, remove them from your file. ///// as an aside, WHY are you using this roundabout method? you can use `$Array.Where({})` to filter quite quickly - if your collection is fairly small..

Comment: Like @Olaf said, using `import-csv` would be much easier than your get-content approach :)

Comment: Instead of outputting to `projects_hash.txt` you should make it a json file which would work with a few extra things :).

Comment: Instead of doing the last line of the foreach loop, try doing `$var=@"
{"hash":"admin","hash2":"support"}
"@` and then `$var = $var |convertfrom-json` then output $var to the file

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right and the source data is in the format you posted you don't have to do  string acrobatics to transform your input data to a usable format. ;-)

You could import your source data with Import-Csv.

```
$SourceData = 
@'
"ID","Name"
"0d769684e36e4cee83b26e8a2b42401b","admin"
"1ba56baa693841199c21b822ccd21dd4","Support"
'@ |
    ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Now that you have structured data you can filter it the way you want. Either by ID ...

```
$DesiredID = "1ba56baa693841199c21b822ccd21dd4"
$SourceData | 
    Where-Object -Property ID -EQ -Value $DesiredID
```

Or by Name ...

```
$DesiredName = "admin"
$SourceData | 
    Where-Object -Property Name -EQ -Value $DesiredName
```

**Edit:**
Just to be very clear about this: I'm not recommending using ConvertFrom-Csv. That's just to make the code easier to copy and to run here from SO. The recommended way of importing the source data would be something like this:

```
$SourceData =
    Import-Csv -Path .\projects.txt -Delimiter ','
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would suggest @Olaf's method, but I am here to provide an alternative.

Instead of using `ConvertFrom-Csv` you could use `ConvertFrom-Json` and the result will be similar.

```
$jsonvar = @"
{}
"@
$jsonvar = $jsonvar | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($line in (Get-Content -encoding ASCII .\projects.txt | select-object -skip 1)){
  $proj_array = $line.split(',')
  $proj_id = $proj_array[0] -Replace '"',""
  $proj_name = $proj_array[1]
  $jsonvar | add-member -value "$proj_name" -name "$proj_id" -MemberType NoteProperty
}
$jsonvar | convertto-json > .\projects_hash.txt
$tempo = get-content .\projects_hash.txt
$projects = @"
$tempo
"@
$projects = $projects | convertfrom-json
$proj_name = $projects.$proj_id
Write-Host "Project name is $proj_name"
```